# Error in data(): "TypeError: this.game.league_person_result[0] is undefined"

Tags: vuejs2

Wanted to do if rendering data properties in vuejs2

I have tried to put into data or computed properties, but it doesn't work.

```
  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
      leagueGameResult: {
        person_id: this.game.person.id,
        person_result: this.game.person_result,
        opponent_id: this.game.opponent.id,
        opponent_result: this.game.opponent_result,
        game_id: this.game.id,
        league_id: this.$route.params.id,
      },
      leagueGameResultEdit: {
        person_id: this.game.person.id,
        person_result: this.game.person_result,
        person_result_id: this.game.league_person_result[0].id ? this.game.league_person_result[0].id : null,
        opponent_id: this.game.opponent.id,
        opponent_result: this.game.opponent_result,
        opponent_result_id: this.game.league_person_result[1].id ? this.game.league_person_result[1].id : null,
        game_id: this.game.id,
        league_id: this.$route.params.id,
      },
    }
  },
```

I want data, that if not exist it would still working, because now its stack, when data is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

So the error suggests that `this.game.league_person_result[0]` is `undefined`, which means you can't access its `id` property. It should be sufficient just to check whether that object is present before trying to grab the `id`.

```js
data() {
  const game = this.game
  const leagueId = this.$route.params.id
  const [league0, league1] = game.league_person_result

  return {
    edit: false,

    leagueGameResult: {
      person_id: game.person.id,
      person_result: game.person_result,
      opponent_id: game.opponent.id,
      opponent_result: game.opponent_result,
      game_id: game.id,
      league_id: leagueId
    },

    leagueGameResultEdit: {
      person_id: game.person.id,
      person_result: game.person_result,
      person_result_id: (league0 && league0.id) || null,
      opponent_id: game.opponent.id,
      opponent_result: game.opponent_result,
      opponent_result_id: (league1 && league1.id) || null,
      game_id: game.id,
      league_id: leagueId
    },
  }
},
```

I've tried to reduce the duplication a little but there's a lot more that can be done given `leagueGameResult` and `leagueGameResultEdit` are almost the same.

I would also suggest trying to move the `league_id` out to a prop rather than grabbing it via `this.$route`. Vue Router allows you to inject route parameters as props.